Android native module - internet access
I wrote a native module (in rust) and connected it to my Android application (via react-native expo).
I'm able to run HTTP requests only to http://10.0.2.2.
I added:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

And android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" that points to:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.0.1</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">ngrok-free.app</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>

But this didn't help, can't access any other site out side of 10.0.2.2.

Hi when you call the ngrok-free.app do you add any auth token, also what exact error you are getting, 404, 502, 400 ?

The issue was specific to reqwest crate under Android using hickory DNS.
Once disabled, everything was fine.
Took a while to figure that out.
